# Can you tie() a filehandle without a bareword glob?

Tags: perl, serial-port, file-handling, tie

I'm trying to use [Device::SerialPort](https://metacpan.org/pod/Device::SerialPort#Methods-used-with-Tied-FileHandles) without a bareword glob, see questions at the bottom.

Here is their example:

```perl
$PortObj = tie (*FH, 'Device::SerialPort', $Configuration_File_Name)
print FH "text";
```

... but polluting the namespace with *FH feels dirty...

I tried `tie(my $fh, ...)` as you would with `open (my $fh, ...)` but `Device::SerialPort` doesn't implement `TIESCALAR` so it gives an error.

This is my dirty hack, but it still uses a bareword and I cant even get it to scope the bareword glob:

```perl
# This does _not_ scope *FH, but shouldn't it?
{
        $port = tie(*FH, 'Device::SerialPort', $ARGV[0]) or die "$ARGV[0]: $!";
        $fh = \*FH;                      # as a GLOB
        $fh = bless(\*FH, 'IO::Handle'); # or as an IO::Handle
}

print $fh "text"; # this works

print FH "text";  # so does this, but shouldn't *FH be scoped?
```

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to tie in a way that does not create a bareword glob?
2. Why do the braces not scope *fh?

Comment: Why do you expect the change to `$fh` to persist the braces, but not the change to `*FH`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `local`.

And I expect this to work too:

```perl
use Symbol qw( gensym );

my $fh = gensym;
tie *$fh, ...
```